# Toggled Class animation not reverting

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to understand why does the animation for a class transition, does not play back, once the class is toggled off.

This is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/joricarmo/pen/bGwaZyv)

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("center");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  top: 0%;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div>some </div>
  <div>some other </div>
</nav>
```

When I click on a DIV, I want it to change it position to the center of the screen, and animate that transition, this works, but once I toggle the class of, the div just "snaps" back to it's original position. Why doesn't it animate back? Is there a way to?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` instead. That way you can use two classes and remove one CSS class name and have it replaced with another so you can animate your DIV back to it original starting point.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as the div looses the `position: absolute;` property, the absolute position is lost. So I suggest you have them always absolutely positionned. Below, I used a loop to set their initial `top` value...

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("center");
});

// To position the divs onload...
$("div").each(function(index, elem) {
  $(elem).css("top", (index * 68) + "px")
})
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  /*   top:0%; */
}

.center {
  /*   position:absolute; */
  background: red;
  top: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div>some </div>
  <div>some other </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the divs position are set to relative. Switching between `position:absolute;` and `position:relative;` cannot be animated. You'd need to adjust your code to animate `top` instead.

```js
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( "center" );
});
```

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  background-color:tomato;
  margin:10px;
  padding:20px;
  font-family:Montserrat;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  transition:all 1s linear;
  top:0%;
  position:absolute;
}
div:nth-child(1){
  top: 0%;
}
div:nth-child(2){
  top: 20%;
}

.center{
  background:red;
  top:50% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div>some </div>
  <div>some other </div>
</nav>
```